# How could I show the loading popop before the fetching data and rendering task are done

Tags: angularjs

I have a page which will call search_hotels method.

It should wait about 2 seconds for the Server returns the JSON.

And the size of the returned JSON contains 2 thounds items.

It also needs 2~3 seconds to process and render all items with ng-repeat.

What the better practice to show the loading window for telling people to wait?

```
        function search_hotels(q_param) {
            roomSkuService.search(q_param).$promise.then(function(resp) {
                _.each(resp, function(item) {
                    var region = item.hotel.region;
                    if ($scope.region.list.indexOf(region) < 0) {
                        $scope.region.list.push(region)
                    }
                });

                $scope.hotels = _.groupBy(resp, function(row) {
                    return row.hotel_id;
                });
            });
        }
```

Comment: Does always you get thousands of result every time you search?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend u use $timeout to hide the loading window after the rendering finishes.

```
function search_hotels(q_param) {
            //show the loading window
            roomSkuService.search(q_param).$promise.then(function(resp) {
                _.each(resp, function(item) {
                    var region = item.hotel.region;
                    if ($scope.region.list.indexOf(region) < 0) {
                        $scope.region.list.push(region)
                    }
                });

                $scope.hotels = _.groupBy(resp, function(row) {
                    return row.hotel_id;
                });

                //execute after rendering
                $timeout(function(){
                    //hide loading window
                },0);
            });
        }
```